# Django DB issue (Interface error: connection closed)

Tags: django, postgresql, cookiecutter-django

**Calling all Pythonistas!** I'm embarrassed to say, but this issue has been plaguing us for 3 weeks!  It's intermittent with no rhyme or reason.

Ubuntu 22.04 running Docker containers (uses the solid [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django)) as a base which we've used successfully for many years.

```
django==4.1.9
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2==2.9.6
```

When submitting a simple registration form, randomly, but very frequently we get the following error:

```
InterfaceError
connection already closed
```

This issue is **ALWAYS** at `django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py in create_cursor at line 269` which is `cursor = self.connection.cursor()`

In Sentry it shows as a "System" error, not an "In-App" error (ie - code flaw).
[image]

The form:

```
class GuestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    time = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])
    # time = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("18:30", "6:30 PM")])

    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "opt_in"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug("=> Init GuestForm")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["time"].choices = get_choices()
    
    def clean_time(self):
        """Return a time."""
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        hours, minutes = cleaned_data["time"].split(":")
        try:
            return datetime.time(int(hours), int(minutes))
        except ValueError as exc:
            raise ValidationError(
                "Invalid value: %(hours)s %(minutes)", code="invalid", params={"hours": hours, "minutes": minutes}
            ) from exc
```

The view:

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
    form_class = GuestForm
    template_name = "tour/register.html"

    tourgroup = None


    @transaction.atomic
    def form_valid(self, form):
        """While we are creating a Guest, we are ultimately creating a TourGroup."""
        # Create or get TourGroup for today
        est = ZoneInfo(settings.TIME_ZONE)
        today = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone(est)
        date = today.date()
        time_ = form.cleaned_data["time"]

        try:
            tourgroup = TourGroup.create(date=date, time=time_)
        except MaxCapacityError:
            tourgroup = TourGroup.objects.get(date=date, time=time_)
            form.add_error(None, f"{tourgroup} tour is at capacity.")
            return super().form_invalid(form)

        # Save guest along with the selected tour
        guest = form.save(commit=False)
        guest.tourgroup = tourgroup
        guest.save()

        self.tourgroup = tourgroup

        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self) -> str:
        """Redirect to the thanks page for the tour created."""
        return reverse("tour:thanks", args=(self.tourgroup.pk,))
```

Interestingly we also get it in random out-of-the-box Django views like a simple "list" view for the `TourGroup` model.  It will occur on almost any database query when using Django views, one request, 500 error, refresh, works fine.  No pattern we see.

We've been spinning wheels, even rebuilt the simple Django app from scratch.  All dependencies match stable stacks we have in the wild and this is the only project with the issue and it's actually a very simple registration site.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Anything change ~3 weeks ago?

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: Something changed as  *...we've used successfully for many years*  and now it is not. What is different about this project vs the others that are not having issues?

Comment: That's the thing.  Nothing.  The entire stack is dependency for dependency (pinned) of projects without issue using the same cookiecutter base.

Comment: 1) Then there is something above the base that is causing the issue. To name some off the top of my head: a) The OS and version. b) Postgres version. c) Network . d) Connection pooler?  2) Have you looked at the Postgres log to see what is closing the connection?

Comment: When the 500 appears, the postgres shows the disconnect, no reason why...it can happen on ANY db query.  Even a simple SELECT. log2023-06-09T16:58:05.949599356Z 2023-06-09 16:58:05.949 UTC [47] LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.015 user=XXXXX database=XXXX host=172.25.0.5 port=37778

Comment: 1) At some point a connection should disconnect so that is not an error in itself.  2) Are the `user=` and `database=` values the ones you expect? 3) Is there anything before or after that log line that looks suspicious?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254015/discussion-between-tsantor-and-adrian-klaver).